# Why do we multiply the square root of two variances when calculating correlation?

Tags: statistics, variance, covariance, correlation

Why, when calculating Correlation, do we divide the $Covariance(x,y)$ by the product of the square root of the variance of $x$, and the square root of the variance of $y$? How should I really interpret the result?

Comment: Because covariance is a unitless quantity. The correlation coefficient is a normalized covariance that tells you the strength of the linear relationship.

Comment: You subtract the means to make both covariance and correlation not depend on locations.  Dividing by the square roots of the variances makes correlation not depend on the scales, so it will be between $-1$ and $+1$ and the extremes indicating a perfect linear relationship ($+1$ indicating an increasing linear relationship, $-1$ decreasing).  Intermediate correlations indicate the lack of a perfect linear relationship and how much (but not how) they deviate from it: see [Anscombe's quartet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anscombe%27s_quartet) for examples of data with correlation of $0.816$